# Поиск строк содержащих искомое значение при помощи Power Query (M)

Tags: excel, search, powerbi

Стоит задача в строках «описание» содержащих набор слов найти строки, которые содержат одни значения, при этом не содержат другие значения.

Мне нужны строки содержащие символ «А» и в тоже время не содержащие символ «G”

Есть строки 
«ASEKDSKSKET”
“CMKFDLSRUK”
“GUIRKXMPLSL”

В результирующей выборке будет только Строка: «ASEKDSKSKET”

Comment: Обязательно PQ? Используйте Расширенный фильтр

Answer (score 0):

Пример фильтрации по указанным параметрам (Excel), фильтрация применена к полю `Word`, см. скриншот.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS. Зачем PQ влепил "Измененный тип" - не знаю. Может, оно и не требуется.

Comment: Ок. Отличный вариант для поиска 1 значения, а если значений несколько?

Comment: @ЛаврентийПалыч Самое очевидное - вывалить эти несколько значений в ещё одну таблицу, и использовать в качестве источника данных обе таблицы. Ну или смотреть мануал, имхо PQ должен уметь что-то типа SQL-ного `WHERE поле IN (список значений)`. PS. Ну не использую я PQ.